# How do my numbers work?

Tags: enigmatic-puzzle

Yesterday, September (1001111 1010000 1011110), I went to the bowling alley with seven of my friends from Carnegie Mellon University -- est. (1010100 0000100 1010100 1111001 1111000 1111001 1111001 1010100 0000000 1110100 0011100 1010100 1011110 1010000 1111001 1011110). We had to play (1111001 0000110 1111001 0011100 1111001 1010100) frames, but I ended up winning with a score of (0000110 1101101 1001111 0000000 1110011 1011100 0000100 1010100 1111000 1101101)!

**Can you decode the numbers in this message?**

#### NEW! HINT 2!

Hints:

> Look for other numbers!

> Is there a number in the puzzle that *isn't* encoded? Maybe that will get you somewhere!

Comment: I *can* decode them as binary, they just don't make sense ;)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your binary numbers encode

> the elements of a 7-segment display, in order mid, UL, LL, bot, LR, UR, top

and what you wrote is:

> Yesterday, September **3rd**, I went to the bowling alley with seven of my friends from Carnegie Mellon University -- est. **nineteen hundred**. We had to play **eleven** frames, but I ended up winning with a score of **153 points**!

Of course

> there is a bit of ambiguity in the decoding; e.g., 1 and L are the same, as are 5 and S.

Comment: Cool! I’ll accept this very soon.

Comment: Actually, do you have any feedback for this puzzle? I feel this one was somewhat of a flop compared to some of my recent ones.

Comment: I suspect it's mostly just a matter of luck -- it depends on who sees what puzzles when. This one was fairly easy (for me, on this occasion -- these things are very variable). Solving process: rot13(gung "rfg." frrzf hfrshy; ybbx hc jura PZH sbhaqrq; abgvpr tebhcf 1 naq 3 ner fnzr, zngpuvat "avargrra"; svyy va "avargrra uhaqerq"; svyy va "3eq" naq "ryrira" tvira rkvfgvat yrggref; fgner sbe n juvyr naq svanyyl abgvpr "cbvagf"; fgner sbe n juvyr ng "yf3 cbvagf" naq nyfb ng h=i; nun!, fbzr fbeg bs _ybbxnyvxrf_; nun! 7-frtzrag qvfcynl.)

Comment: I did look at the hints before actually trying to solve the puzzle. I don't _think_ they made much difference, but I could be wrong.

Comment: Thanks for playing along! :):)